# How to get the current time in UTC, add some minutes to it and the convert it to a specified format in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, time, simpledateformat, utc

I found different topics on this subject but couldn't find a proper solution to my problem yet. How can I get the current UTC time, add for example 60 minutes to it, and the display it in this format: **HH:mm:ss** ? Is it possible? Thanks

I used this to get the UTC time, but I don't know how to add minutes to it and the change the format to display:

```kotlin
val df: DateFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance()
df.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("utc")
val utcTime: String = df.format(Date())
```

I also tried this function but it displays the current time from the device:

```kotlin
fun getDate(milliSeconds: Long, dateFormat: String?): String? {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat)
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeInMillis = milliSeconds
    return formatter.format(calendar.time)
}
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first two in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `java.time` here, you can get the current time of a specific offset or even time zone and output it afterwards using the desired pattern:

```kotlin
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.ZoneOffset
import java.time.OffsetDateTime

fun main() {
    val dateTime = getDateTimeFormatted(50, "HH:mm:ss")
    println(dateTime)
}

fun getDateTimeFormatted(minutesToAdd: Long, pattern: String): String {
    // get current time in UTC, no millis needed
    val nowInUtc = OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC)
    // add some minutes to it
    val someMinutesLater = nowInUtc.plusMinutes(minutesToAdd)
    // return the result in the given pattern
    return someMinutesLater.format(
        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)
    )
}
```

The output of an execution some seconds before posting this was:

```
09:43:00
```

If you are supporting older API versions than 26, you might find out Java 8 features are not directly available there.
You can use them anyway, just read the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), the most recent way is [API Desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)

Comment: I'm getting this error: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/ZoneOffset;. I think it is related to the version of Android

Comment: @Razvan22 Have you imported the classes? Could be related to the Android API version, yes... That's a thing you have to fix yourself, I'm afraid... Check my edit, especially the links posted at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: Yes, I did. I'm supporting older API versions than 26, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Razvan22 Yes, that is the problem. Will be totally worth it to put effort in making your project ready for Java 8.

Answer (score -3):

```
var dateformat  = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
dateformat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
var date = Date()
date.hours = date.hours +2
date.minutes = date.minutes + 30
Log.e("date",dateformat.format(date))
```